# Dominated convergence theorem where the sequence is dominated by another sequence, and the convergence is in measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider sequences of random variables $(X_n), (Y_n)$ with $|X_n|<Y_n$. Suppose $(Y_n)$ converges in probability to $Y$, and $EY_n \to EY$. I have to show that, if $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in probability, $EX_n \to EX$. I have no idea of where to start. I have seen a question here in stackexchange that answers this for the case where $(Y_n)$ is constant, and would like some tips on how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof sketch: The claim is a well known generalization of the dominated convergence theorem if we replace convergence in measure with a.e. convergence. Note the famous result that a sequence $y_n$ in a topological space $X$ converges to $y$ if and only if every subsequence of $y_n$ has a further subsequence that converges to $y$. Now apply this result to show that $E(X_n) \to E(X)$. Use the fact that convergence in measure implies convergence of a subsequence a.e.